# Create contact with custom ID - SugarCrm API v10 REST

Tags: php, api, sugarcrm

I'm trying to POST to sugarCrms API to create a contact.

I have everything mapping fine, except for the actual 'id' of the Contact.  Sugar uses it's own UUID for creating modules, but I would like to use my own.

```
//$mapped['id']         = $unmapped->customer_id;
$mapped['first_name'] = $unmapped->first_name;
$mapped['last_name']  = $unmapped->last_name;
```

Like I said, everything works well when creating a Contact, but Sugar is still using it's own ID.  I've tried `'ID'` as well.  When I use the key of `id` it throws a internal server error, so I'm assuming its the wrong key, or I need to do something additional.

I'm using key's that the response sends back and cannot find any information on how to use my own ID.

Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The id I was using was previously used for a contact (my test account).  Even after deletion of that contact, the ID was not allowed to be used (for some odd reason), so it threw a server error.

Sugar has error logs located in the System Settings of the Admin area and I should have looked there earlier.

Comment: If the record is still in the database it's only a soft delete